# How to get a random enum in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, enums

How to get a random item from an enumeration?

```
enum Colors {
  Red, Green, Blue
}

function getRandomColor(): Color {
  // return a random Color (Red, Green, Blue) here
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

After *much inspiration* from the other solutions, and the `keyof` keyword, here is a **generic method** that returns a **typesafe random enum**.

```
function randomEnum<T>(anEnum: T extends object): T[keyof T] {
  const enumValues = Object.keys(anEnum)
    .map(n => Number.parseInt(n))
    .filter(n => !Number.isNaN(n)) as unknown as T[keyof T][]
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length)
  const randomEnumValue = enumValues[randomIndex]
  return randomEnumValue;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
interface MyEnum {X, Y, Z}
const myRandomValue = randomEnum(MyEnum)
```

`myRandomValue` will be of type `MyEnum`.

Comment: Instead of `Object.keys(anEnum).map(n => Number.parseInt(n))` couldn’t you use `Object.values(anEnum).map(n => +n)`? The enum’s keys are all strings whereas its values are a mix of numbers and strings (the numbers being the actual enum values and the strings being its keys). For example, given `enum Bool { FALSE, TRUE }`, `Object.keys(Bool)` would return `["0", "1", "FALSE", "TRUE"]` (all strings) but `Object.values(Bool)` would return `["FALSE", "TRUE", 0, 1]` (numbers and strings).

Comment: hmm, didnt work for me, is this for number based enums?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, have a lot of errors 
1) Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object'
2) Property 'parseInt' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later
3) Property 'isNaN' does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later

Comment: most likely kotlin as changed their syntax. i will have a look and adjust.

Comment: Just tried this with the newest Angular. Works on plain enums (with numeric values) but breaks when I create an enum with string values like `enum Stuff {A="A", B="B"}`. Edit: the answer by Kabir works, though.

Comment: why do you need to filter elements that are not numbers? you could just divide the length of keys by 2 and choose and random index in that range.

Answer (score 28):

Most of the above answers are returning the enum keys, but don't we really care about the enum values?

If you are using lodash, this is actually as simple as:

```
_.sample(Object.values(MyEnum))
```

If you're not using lodash, or you want this as its own function, we can still get a type-safe random enum by modifying @Steven Spungin's answer to look like:

```
function randomEnum<T>(anEnum: T): T[keyof T] {
  const enumValues = (Object.values(anEnum) as unknown) as T[keyof T][];
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length);
  return enumValues[randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: what is `myEnum` in your lodash example?

Comment: Something weird happens with `Object.values(myEnum)` - it returns an array of mixed strings and numbers like `['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 0, 1, 2]` for the Colors enum above. Object.keys does the same except the number are also strings in that case: `['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', '0', '1', '2']`

Answer (score 6):

How about this, using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) from es2017 (not supported by IE and support in other browsers is more recent):

```js
function randEnumValue<T>(enumObj: T): T[keyof T] {
  const enumValues = Object.values(enumObj);
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length);
  
  return enumValues[index];
}
```

Comment: I think you need `extends object` on `T`, otherwise TypeScript complains (at least with strict options set). [Version as above that complains](https://tsplay.dev/mxqEKW), [Version with `extends object` that doesn't complain](https://tsplay.dev/WzQq3m)

Answer (score 6):

So no answer did work for me, I end up doing like this:

having the following enum

```
export enum Jokenpo {
  PAPER = 'PAPER',
  ROCK = 'ROCK',
  SCISSOR = 'SCISSOR',
}
```

to random select

```
const index= Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Jokenpo).length);
const value= Object.values(Jokenpo)[index];

return Jokenpo[value];
```

I'm just getting a random value from the enums and using it to convert to the real thing.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to support string or heterogeneous enums, I might suggest a function like this:

```
const randomEnumKey = enumeration => {
  const keys = Object.keys(enumeration)
    .filter(k => !(Math.abs(Number.parseInt(k)) + 1));
  const enumKey = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
  
  return enumKey;
};
```

To get a random value:

```
const randomEnumValue = (enumeration) => enumeration[randomEnumKey(enumeration)];
```

Or simply:

```
MyEnum[randomEnumKey(MyEnum)]
```

Example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-random-enum

Comment: This is great! For my use case I needed a bit more type safety so I modified the randomEnumKey like so: `const randomEnumKey = <T>(enumeration: T): keyof T => {` ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-random-enum-nfk4ab?file=index.ts

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I could come up with, but it looks like a hack and depends on the implementation of `enum` in TypeScript, which I'm not sure is guaranteed to stay the same.

Given an enumeration such as

```
enum Color { Red, Green, Blue }
```

if we `console.log` it, we get the following output.

```
{
  '0': 'Red',
  '1': 'Green',
  '2': 'Blue',
  Red: 0,
  Green: 1,
  Blue: 2,
}
```

This means we can go through this object's keys and grab only numeric values, like this:

```
const enumValues = Object.keys(Color)
  .map(n => Number.parseInt(n))
  .filter(n => !Number.isNaN(n))
```

In our case, `enumValues` is now `[0, 1, 2]`. We now only have to pick one of these, at random. There's a good implementation of a function which returns a [random integer between two values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values), which is exactly what we need to randomly select an index.

```
const randomIndex = getRandomInt(0, enumValues.length)
```

Now we just pick the random enumeration value:

```
const randomEnumValue = enumValues[randomIndex]
```

Comment: TSLint gives the error: `TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Color'` on your last line

Comment: Hmm, maybe something changed in the meantime or we have different compiler flags. Unfortunately I am currently unable to test it out, and I don't think I remember what version this was. :/

Comment: Darn, no worries :/ I'm working on a different solution myself - I'm also using SonarTS alongside TSLint which has pretty strict rules

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Fixed type issue.

Tidying up @ShailendraSingh's answer a bit, if the enum is defined as in the question, without any custom indexes, then this is a simple approach:

```
enum Color {
  Red, Green, Blue
}
  
function getRandomColor(): Color {
  var key = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Color).length / 2);
  return Color[key];
}
```

Note that the return type `Color` here (as requested in the question) is actually the enum index and not a color name.

Comment: TS Lint gives the error: `TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Color'`

Comment: That's not linter, that's Typescript itself.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 2 here?

Comment: @Aeternus, it's a quirk of how numeric enums (the default TS enum type) are implemented - the indices are treated as keys too. In this specific example, `Object.keys(Color)` returns the 6 keys `0,1,2,Red,Green,BlueRed` , so we have to divide by two. This wouldn't be an issue with string enums, but the implementation would then need to be a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

You can find below code to get things done.

```
enum Colors {
  Red,
  blue,
  pink,
  yellow,
  Orange
}

function getRandomColor(): string {
  // returns the length
  const len = (Object.keys(Colors).length / 2) - 1;
  // calculate random number
  const item = (Math.floor(Math.random() * len) + 0);

  return Colors[item];
}
```

Comment: This will fail if you specify an enum like `enum Colors { Red: 100, Blue }`

Comment: yes but i have given the answer for the format specified in question and its work perfectly fine for that.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović it looks like for that, you could do 


    `const item = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Colors).length); const i2 = Object.keys(Colors)[item]; return Colors[i2];`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @sarink answer.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

export function getRandomValueFromEnum<E>(enumeration: { [s: string]: E } | ArrayLike<E>): E {
  return _.sample(Object.values(enumeration)) as E;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@faker-js/faker) package (I use it for tests), you can use the following.
This solution utilizes the [arrayElement](https://fakerjs.dev/api/helpers.html#arrayelement) function to pick a random color from the Colors enum.

```js
// Get an array of all values in the Colors enum
const colorValues = Object.values(Colors);

// Use arrayElement from faker to pick a random color from the array
const randomColor = faker.helpers.arrayElement(colorValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not perfect, but could try something like this..

```
function getRandomEnum(input: object): any {
  const inputTransform: { [key: string]: string } = input as { [key: string]: string };
  const keysToArray = Object.keys(inputTransform);
  const valuesToArray = keysToArray.map(key => inputTransform[key]);

  if (!isNaN(parseInt(keysToArray[0], 10))) {
    const len = keysToArray.length;

    while (keysToArray.length !== len / 2) {
      keysToArray.shift();
      valuesToArray.shift();
    }
  }

  const randIndex = Math.floor(keysToArray.length * Math.random());

  return valuesToArray[randIndex];
}
```

Tested with...

```
enum Names {
  foo,
  bar,
  baz,
  // foo = "fooZZZ",
  // bar = "barZZZ",
  // baz = "bazZZZ",
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  const result = getRandomEnum(Names);
  if (result === Names.foo) console.log(`${result} is foo`);
  else if (result === Names.bar) console.log(`${result} is bar`);
  else if (result === Names.baz) console.log(`${result} is baz`);
}
```

Outputs...

```
0 is foo
0 is foo
2 is baz
0 is foo
2 is baz
2 is baz
1 is bar
1 is bar
2 is baz
1 is bar
```

or...

```
bazZZZ is baz
bazZZZ is baz
bazZZZ is baz
barZZZ is bar
bazZZZ is baz
barZZZ is bar
barZZZ is bar
fooZZZ is foo
barZZZ is bar
fooZZZ is foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Colors {
  Red, Green, Blue
}

const keys = Object.keys(Colors)
const real_keys = keys.slice(keys.length / 2,keys.length)
const random =  real_keys[Math.floor(Math.random()*real_keys.length)]
console.log(random)
```

Tested on TypeScript 3.5.2 using ESNext. It's quite simple.

Bonus using namespace

```
enum Colors {
  Red,
  Green,
  Blue,
}
namespace Colors {
  // You need to minus the function inside your namespace
  // That's why I had - 1
  // Because instead of 0,1,2,red,green,blue = 6
  // It will be 0,1,2,red,green,blue,Random = 7
  export function Random(): any {
    const length = ((Object.keys(Colors).length - 1) / 2)
    return Colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * length / 2)]
  }
}

console.log(Colors.Random())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that worked for me in ES5:

```
function getRandomEnum<T extends object>(anEnum: T): T[keyof T] {
  const enumValues = Object.keys(anEnum)
    .filter(key => typeof anEnum[key as keyof typeof anEnum] === 'number')
    .map(key => key);
 
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length)
  
  return anEnum[randomIndex as keyof T];
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's different than other answers and why is ES5 relevant?

Comment: Number.parseInt() and Number.isNan() does not exist on type 'NumberConstructor' when I target ES5 in TypeScript. I also had trouble when leaving out <T extends object> in the signature! The solution of this question works nice if you target greater than ES5. I guess the javascript file still will work, but wanted to remove the linter errors.

Comment: why this code returns a random number sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

Ease solution that works with all types of enums

```
function randomEnum<T extends Record<string, number | string>>(anEnum: T): T[keyof T] {
  const enumValues = getEnumValues(anEnum);
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length);
        
  return enumValues[randomIndex];
}
```

Used [lodash](https://lodash.com/), but function can be rewritten without it

```
function getEnumValues<T extends Record<string, number | string>>(anEnum: T): Array<T[keyof T]> {
  const enumClone = _.clone(anEnum);

  _.forEach(enumClone, (_value: number | string, key: string) => {
      if (!isNaN(Number(key))) {
        delete enumClone[key];
      }
    });

  return _.values(enumClone) as Array<T[keyof T]>;
}

enum Status { active, pending }
enum Type { active = 'active', pending = 'pending' } 
enum Mixed { active = 'active', pending = 1 }

randomEnum(Status) // (Return random between 0,1) 
randomEnum(Type) // (Return 'active' or 'pending' string) 
randomEnum(Mixed) // (Return 'active' or 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on @Steven Spungin answer, and skipping the unnecessary filtering:

```js
function randomEnum<T>(anEnum: T): T[keyof T] {
    const enumValues = Object.keys(anEnum) as T[keyof T][];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * enumValues.length / 2);
    return enumValues[randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: Why are you dividing by 2 in randomIndex?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that is because TypeScript compiles enums to objects with each element's name AND index as the keys, the names first and them the indeces. So by dividing by two we only choose a random enum name. This is what the object looks like: `const MyEnum = {foo: 1 , bar: 2, '1': 1, '2': 2, ..etc}`. `Object.keys` would return: `['foo', 'bar', '1', '2']`

Answer (score -1):

this is working for me.

```js
enum Colors {
  Red = 'Red', 
  Green = 'Green', 
  Blue = 'Blue',
};

function getRandomInt(min: number, max: number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

const colorKeys = Object.keys(Colors) as (keyof typeof Colors)[];

const randomColor = Colors[
  colorKeys[
    getRandomInt(0, colorKeys.length)
  ]
];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).