# How to use string interpolation and receive a random value from an enum?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, string-interpolation

What I have to do is as follows:
I have a component with an array of offers. An offer consists of several things, but one of them has to be a status which has to be a string-based enum.
Offers with random values for several attributes have to be created, one of them is the status of the offer as an enum. This can be “NEW”, “FOR_SALE”, “SOLD”, “PAID”, “DELIVERED”, “CLOSED”, “EXPIRED”, and “WITHDRAWN”. A random offer must be generated with a method that creates this offer with randomized attributes for everything as well as a random status from the enum.

Now I have tried lots of things and I just cannot figure out how to use the enum in this scenario. String interpolation on the enum does not seem to do anything or put out any value from the enum and I can't see how to apply randomization on the enum as you don't seem to be able to apply anything to the enum itself.

```
export class Overview1Component implements OnInit {
  private offers: Offer[];
```

```
export class Offer {
  public title: string;
  public sellDate: Date;
  public description: string;
  public auctionStatus: AuctionStatus;
  public numberOfBids: number;
  public valueHighestBid: number;
}

export enum AuctionStatus {
  NEW = 1,
  FOR_SALE = 2,
  SOLD = 3,
  PAID = 4,
  DELIVERED = 5,
  CLOSED = 6,
  EXPIRED = 7,
  WITHDRAWN = 8
}
```

Is there a flaw in my approach itself for the enumerator? How would I pick out a random value from the enum and use string interpolation to display this in my HTML?

---

Some further information:

Random offers are made with the following method:

```
 public addRandomOffer(): void {
    const newOffer = new Offer();
    newOffer.title = 'This great article offer-' + (this.offers.length);
    const fromDate = new Date(2005, 0, 1);
    const toDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1);
    newOffer.sellDate = this.getRandomDate(fromDate, toDate, 0, 23);
    newOffer.numberOfBids = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30 + 1);
    if (newOffer.numberOfBids === 0) {
      newOffer.valueHighestBid = 0;
    } else {
      newOffer.valueHighestBid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200 + 1);
    }
    this.offers.push(newOffer);
  }
```

As you can see there is currently nothing in here for setting or randomizing the status, as I can't figure out how to do anything with it.

This is done so that random offers can be displayed on a component of overview of offers.

[Image of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wLvF.png)

In the HTML for printing the offers I currently have the following:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let offer of offers">
    <td>{{offer.title}}</td>
    <td>{{offer.sellDate}}</td>
    <td>{{offer.auctionStatus}}</td>
    <td>{{offer.numberOfBids}}</td>
    <td>€{{offer.valueHighestBid}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230998/how-to-get-a-random-enum-in-typescript

Comment: Could you post the code where you are generating the random offer? It doesn't matter it is failing in generating the random enum, that's what we need to check and help you with

Comment: I have added some extra information in the post.

Answer (score 0):

A shortened version :

```js
class Offer {
  constructor() {
    this.auctionStatus = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
  }

}

const offer = new Offer();
console.log(offer.auctionStatus);
```

Easy as that.

Although, since you asked it, I strongly advise to use enums. They don't have their place in JS. So just use an object instead.

(But that's personal preference).

Answer (score 0):

You can access a random enum value by index accessor as

```
AuctionStatus[Math.trunc(Math.random() * 8 + 1)]
```

You can use a neat trick to access the number of values in enum as

```
Object.keys(AuctionStatus).length / 2
```

Stackblitz at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-get-random-enum-value

Comment: I would use `trunc` instead of `floor`, and you have to add 1 (it starts at 1, not 0). For the second peice of code, wouldn't that return 4 everytime ?

Comment: Oooooooh, keys are actually values too ! well, needlessly complicated, but you taught me something here, so thank you !

Comment: @Maryannah Even you taught me `trunc` Thanks a lot!