# Generate Object of Random Value from Literal Type

Tags: typescript, types, literals

I'm using a library which has a declared type as such:

```
type MyType = "value1" | "value2" | "value3";
```

I would like to create an object which holds the value of one of the possible values, randomly selected.

I was originally thinking that the `MyType` type was defined as an `enum`, but instead it is defined as above. I was referencing this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55699349

Essentially, I'm looking for a generic solution to retrieving the possible values of a literal type at runtime, and then grabbing one of them at random. Here is a non-working version of what I'm looking for: [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwIZgCZwLYDVUA2IApgDwAqAfABQB09qyA5gM4Bci5A2gLoCUHcogDeAKEQpiUEMiSNWXALKooAC1rACcOMmrK1tNJhzU+iAFSJ5LWgWJgmavjwDcogL6jRUAJ4AHYkRFH3J-QIBeRAAiADdCEgBGKMQAH2i4omIAJmS02PjiAGYo0QgEFigUdCxsYNCAxEjTRsoq4zwCvRCwvjdS8srsboCOOrDGtpqxgNM3AHo5xAADIfriJcQYFkQwOAB3RARAuGBENUC1ZGJAvzgWFhgAIztEDJJt4B0z1UCl6fWzmFaF4ymAWHA7LY4ExqKsei4gA)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the type supposed to be `MyType`? It's random after all.

Comment: I'm sorry-- I'm not sure I understand your question @kelly. I'm hoping to have on object which stores the value of one of the valid values, either `"value1"`, `"value2"`, or `"value3"`. It's defined as a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDR3jW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply and want me to be notified, please mention me via @jcalz)

Comment: @jcalz -- Yes, that's the idea. But (and maybe I wasn't clear about this) I'd like to not need to create the function by copy-pasting the type values and hard-coding them into the `randomMyType` function. Instead, I'd like the function to be generic and the possible values inferred automatically. Does that make sense? I have modified your example to show what I'm aiming for, and pasted into the original question. (It obviously won't compile because I don't know the solution)

Comment: You cannot use types to influence the runtime behavior of a program, as types will be erased. But instead of defining `type MyType = "value1" | "value2" | "value3";`, you could define `const myValues = ["value1", "value2", "value3"] as const;` and`type MyType = (typeof myValues)[number];`, and then you can use `myValues` as an argument to `randomType`

Comment: The answer is "no, this is impossible"; types are [erased](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types). You will always have better luck starting with values and deriving types from them, than the other way around. If you already have the type then you're going to need redundancy somewhere. I'm inclined to close this as a dup of [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/71594686/how-to-generate-value-from-type) if the question is really about getting values from types. If you're a version that does the reverse, then I can write up an answer. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you @GuillaumeBrunerie and @jcalz. Those both answer the question. I was hoping that types were preserved similar to how the `enum`s seem to have their values stored in a dict are runtime, but I see now that that is not true. I see how my question is related to the other question. Feel free to answer/close as appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned through the comments that this is not possible, due to types being erased. More details are available here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types

Answer (score 1):

### **Use an array as source-of-truth**

Define your values as a regular array, and use it for *both* your typing and generating a random selection in runtime.

This is possible with TS 3.4, using [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

**Steps**

**1. Make an array, and add `as const` at the end.**

```
const myValues = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] as const
```

**2. Make a type using the array**

Using `typeof someArray[number]` ultimately becomes a union of all the entries in the array; the type can only be one of the array entries.

```
type myType = typeof myValues[number]
```

**3. Select a random array entry**

For an instance of `myType`, select a random array entry; only the array entries are allowed (by Typescript).

```
const someInstance:myType = myValues[myValues.length * Math.random() | 0]
```

or just set explicit values:

```
// Fails (typescript warning because it doesn't exist in the array)
const someInstance:myType = 'Foo' 

// Works (no typescript warning)
const someInstance:myType = 'value3'
```

**Side note**

In this context, look into *runtime* type checking (which Typescript doesn't provide). Libraries like [Zod](https://zod.dev) provide this, and integrate with TS, however this may change how you shape your sources-of-truth (ie your array).